# No state in response in signinRedirectCallback using Oidc-Client.js

Tags: angular, single-page-application, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

We are using Oidc-Client authentication flow in Single page application and below are the clarifications. Kindly help on same.

Current Scenario :

1. In Login screen, when signinRedirect method called then it is hitting IDSRV and token got generated.
2. When trying to call signinRedirectCallback method in redirect url where it is invoked, then we are getting below runtime error.

Expected Scenario:

1. when trying to call signinRedirectCallback method then it should get user's state in response so that  automatic silent renew will work.

Kindly let us know if any settings are missing or else any parameter need to be passed in signinRedirect()?

**Below are the sample code**

```
var settings = {
  authority: "https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxx/v1", 
  client_id: "https://xxx.xxx.com/",
  redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html",
  post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000/logout.html", 
  revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,      
  response_type: "id_token token",
  scope: "openid read:xxxx read:xxxx",
  state: true,
  filterProtocolClaims: true,  
  loadUserInfo: true,
  nonce:true, 
  clearHashAfterLogin: true,
  automaticSilentRenew: true,     
  silent_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:3000/silent-refresh.html',      
  monitorsession:true,  
  metadata: {        
    issuer: 'https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/v1',                    
    authorization_endpoint:  "https://xxx.xxx.com/xxxxx/v1/connect/authorize"                
   
}    
};


signinRedirect = () => {
    this.UserManager.signinRedirect().then(function() {
      console.log("signinRedirect done");
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  };

 signinRedirectCallback = () => {
    this.UserManager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      console.log("signinRedirectCallback", user);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("error:"+err);
      });
  };
```

**Issue :**
oidc-client.min.js:1 OidcClient.readSigninResponseState: No state in response

Comment: Hi team, any update on this?

Comment: Hi team, any thought of  this request?

Comment: Hi team, anyone have you had a chance looking into this?

Comment: You can use signinRedirect({ state: { bar: 15 } }); //Generates 15 char state value.